How can I transpose SCILAB/MATLAB code with for loop into Mathematica?
How can I transpose the following SCILAB/MATLAB code into MATHEMATICA?
I took a look at similar questions, but none of them seemed to provide a solution.

a0 = 1;a1 = 2;a2 = 1;b0 = 1;b1 = -1.8;b2 = 0.81;
N = 100;
x = ones(N,1);
y = zeros(N,1);
for n = 3:N
  y(n) = a0*x(n)+a1*x(n-1)+a2*x(n-2)-b0*y(n)-b1*y(n-1)-b2*y(n-2);
end
clf();
plot(y)


The plot is the following one :


What have you tried?

This should do it
a0 = 1;a1 = 2;a2 = 1;b0 = 1;b1 = -1.8;b2 = 0.81;
capN = 100; (*N is a predefined MMA function so use capN instead*)
x = Table[1,{capN}];
y = Table[0,{capN}];
For[n = 3,n<=capN,n++,
  y[[n]] = a0*x[[n]]+a1*x[[n-1]]+a2*x[[n-2]]-b0*y[[n]]-b1*y[[n-1]]-b2*y[[n-2]]
]
ListPlot[y]  (* Optionally use ListPlot[y,Joined->True] instead*)


Thank you very much, Bill. It does, and rather well.
Do you think it is possible to do it with RecrrenceTable?
I tried, but the result is not correct.

Your y[[n]] = stuff-b0*y[[n]]-morestuff worries me. Having y[n] on both sides of a recurrence equation confuses me and confuses MMA. I tried moving that to the left hand side and that doesn't work either. Perhaps if you could edit your question to explain where this came from and how you got your equation then I might be able to figure it out. Is there any chance that having y[n] on both sides might be an error?

This RecurrenceTable[{y[n] == a0*1+a1*1+a2*1-b0*0-b1*y[n-1]-b2*y[n-2],y[2]==0, y[1]==0},y,{n,3,100}] is the closest I can get at the moment. That assumes all x[[i]]==1 and y[[i]]==0 initially and doesn't assign any values to x or y or n before this starts.

Yes you are right. There is a mistake in the recurrence equation. The good one is the following one : y(n)=(a0/b0)*x(n)+(a1/b0)*x(n-1)+(a2/b0)*x(n-2)-(b1/b0)*y(n-1)-(b2/b0)*y(n-2)
